# MP Android Chart-How to display last grid line in horizontal bar chart

Tags: android

I have been using MP android v2.2.4 chart's Bar chart in my android application. I am unable to display last grid line, So please help me to solve my problem.
Thank you in Advance

Have a look at the image below :

[image: graph image]

Comment: try this `YAxis yr = mChart.getAxisRight();
  yr.setDrawAxisLine(true);`

Comment: May be you need to give right offset using `mChart.setExtraRightOffset (20f);`

Comment: Thank you @MohammedFarhan, but it's not working. Your code displayed bottom axis line.